# need EditText with readonly indent

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

Does anyone have ideas on how to achieve a blank indent on the first line of an EditText such that the user cannot modify the indent?

My goal is to superimpose some other info (possibly graphics) in the indent area and still allow the rest of the EditText to wrap long lines back to the normal left margin.

Fallback would be to add a separate line or column for the "other info", but that isn't as good a use of the screen real estate.

Perhaps there is better way to do this.  Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on what are you trying to do but you can "modify" dinamically the text while is prompted.

Use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) that offers you three method called in order. Try in debug with some breakpoints to understand better the variables and use them!

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

Comment: I'm familiar with TextWatcher, but using it didn't even cross my mind.  Thanks so much.  I'll add that it's kind of a kludgy solution, but it should work and be reasonably stable across Android releases.