# What happens after my button does its job? (ANDROID)

Tags: java, android

So I created a basic converter app that converts miles to kilometer. In the app, the user can either enter values on the miles edittext or kilometers edittext. After entering a value and pressing on the "convert" button, the value is converted and displayed accordingly. What I really wanted to do is remove the convert button so that the conversion is done as the user is  enter the input simultaneously. I did some research and found out about textlistener but failed miserably in implementing it.

So i thought of keeping the button, and going on a different route. What i'm trying to do is for example, if the user first enters value on the miles edit text and converts it to kms. Then when the user presses on the kilometers edit text, I want the edit text on both miles and kilometers to be blank so that the user doesnt have to keep erasing the values.

I thought about this a lot. I can do it, but I'm confused about where to put the code, since there is only one method that I created, i.e. convertLength().

I am thoroughly confused, so any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
package com.abhinavbhatta.converter;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class ConvertLength extends Activity {
    Button clength;
    EditText mi;
    EditText km;

    double milesValue;
    double kmValue;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert_length);

}       


public void convertLength(View view){
    clength = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clength);

    mi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mi);
    km = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_km);       

    Intent intentLength = getIntent();

    if (mi.isFocused()){

        milesValue = Double.parseDouble(mi.getText().toString());
        kmValue = milesValue * 1.6;
        km.setText( String.format( "%.2f", kmValue ) );


    }

    if (km.isFocused()){
        kmValue = Double.parseDouble(km.getText().toString());
        milesValue = kmValue/(1.6);
        mi.setText( String.format( "%.2f", milesValue ) );      

    }

}



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.convert_length, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: First of all, your `convertLength()` won't get called ever.

Comment: Probably he put the method in the onClick in the xml?

Comment: Yes, it's defined in the XML

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a TextWatcher to do some dynamic action.

Read this other answer to find out more. :)

[need EditText with readonly indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754663/need-edittext-with-readonly-indent/14755118#14755118)

Comment: Hi @Enrichman Thanks for the post. I did try to implement textwatcher but i got an error. If i were to implement it again, where would it go? Under onCreate or within the convertLength() itself?

Comment: Well, the convertLenght should be totally removed if you want to do a dynamic conversion. I would put in the onCreate two text watcher, one for each edittext. If you still have a problem I will edit my answer with an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post which  code  you are using for resetting the values...or you can try this :

```
EditText edit;
edit.setText(null);
```

Comment: I did try using a reset method using setText(""); but where would it go? If it goes in the convertLength method it would reset the output.

Comment: @AbhinavBhatta can you try it with View.OnTouchListener. This is called when the user performs an action qualified as a touch event.

Comment: you can try it    `edit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});`